# Wrong frame-rate, corrupted playback of isom/mp4 files remuxed from H.264/AC3 MPEG-TS

Tags: ffmpeg, mp4, file-formats, framerate, mpeg

NOTE: This question is superceded by [this new one](https://video.stackexchange.com/q/23344/), please do not answer below this post.

**What happened?**

- [Edit] DVB file ('file1') in TS format of H.264/AC3@50i cannot be properly remuxed into any of the following formats: isom/mp4; QuickTime MOV; Matroska
- Another DVB file ('file2') in TS format of MPEG-2/MP2@59.94i can be properly remuxed into any of the following formats: MPEG; isom/mp4. QuickTime MOV and Matroska are not tried.
- [Update] Still another one in TS format of H.264/AAC@29.97p *can* be properly remuxed into isom/mp4 without a hitch, not requiring any ffmpeg switches other than -i, -c copy.

**Technical details**

- FFMpeg reports millions of the following error messages, with or without any possible combination of these switches: -fflags +genpts, -fflags +igndts, -fflags +discardcorrupt

  - Command line is `ffmpeg.exe -fflags +igndts -fflags +genpts -fflags +discardcorrupt -i INPUT -c copy -format mp4 OUTPUT`
  - Error Message 1:
        [mp4 @ address] pts has no value
        Last message repeated xxx times
  - Error Message 2:
       [mp4 @ address] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:0. Previous ... Current ... Changing to ... , blah blah
- AVIDemux completes operation with wrong metadata and faulty playback. File properties and playback behaviour resembles that created by FFMpeg

  - Frame-rate becomes variable, should be 50i
  - Average frame-rate is not the correct value, showing very strange numbers
  - Playback frame-rate is abnormal, oscillating btw. 59.94 and 39.xx
- [Edit] MP4box reports the following warnings for 2 times, and produces jagged picture with wrong frame-rate as mentioned above. If you view the resultant video very carefully you will see the image with many blocks; this is not found in the original file.

  - Command line is  `mp4box.exe -fps 50 -add "INPUT#video" OUTPUT`
  - Error Message:
       [MPEG-2 TS] PID xx PCR discontinuity signaled but diff is small (diff xx us - PCR diff xx vs prev PCR diff 0) - ignore it

**My questions, in detail**

1   What on earth is "DTS" and "PTS"? They seem to be obsructing a successful remux.
2   Is this due to corrupted file or software bug (see https://trac.ffmpeg.org/ticket/4768 and https://trac.ffmpeg.org/ticket/502)?
3   If this is a software bug what are the work-arounds?
4   Any workable solution that remuxes MPEG Transport Streams to MP4 are welcome. MPEG-TS takes up too much overhead and are not well supported across platforms and systems.

**Diagnostic Information**
-   MediaInfo dump of file1,  file2, and  file1 remuxed into mp4 by FFMpeg
http://pastebin.ca/3966322

Comment: What does corrupted playback mean - decoding errors? Is the playback speed always wrong or it varies?

Comment: @Mulvya, playback speed is always wrong; frame image seems fine; the decoder can work but apparently the file isn't usable.

Comment: Does a TS to TS remux preserve playback rate? The `store method` of file1 is unusual. Try with [ffmbc](https://github.com/bcoudurier/FFmbc). If you can't compile, get an older binary from https://www.videohelp.com/software/ffmbc

Comment: @Mulvya , TS→TS remux works in FFMpeg with the following options specified: `-mpegts_service_type advanced_codec_digital_hdtv -mpegts_m2ts_mode false -mpegts_flags system_b`; works in FFMbc with `-fflags +genpts` specified. TS→mp4 succeeded in FFMbc (0.7.2) with `-fflags +genpts -f mp4` specified. The ffmbc hack worked for this file and some others, the rest still failed. The issue appears to be centered around timestamping. A [new question](https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/23344/) has been posted to supercede this one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer part of your question (and add a couple of other abbreviations you will run into):

- PTS = Presentation Time Stamp
- DTS = Decode Time Stamp
- PCR = Program Clock Reference
- SCR = System Clock Reference

[MPEG elementary streams](http://download.tek.com/document/25W-11418-10.pdf) reorder the frames for transmission. The PTS indicates the order that the frames should be re-assembled into. The DTS lets the decoder know if a frame needs to be decoded earlier than it is displayed (because a P or B frame references it). The PCR or SCR are the time scale that the PTS and DTS reference.

[tstools](https://github.com/OlivierLeBozec/tstools) and other transport stream analyzers can help you determine if the PCR/PTS/DTS issue is in the source file or not.

Comment: The links you've provided are just fabulous! However, I'm getting more confused after reading the PDF pp. 43-44. Although the PTS may not be monotonous as a result of bidirectional encoding, this should not cause frustrations for a proper (de)muxer because (i) the stream is transmitted and received according to the DTS which has to be (a) monotonous and (b) <= PTS-1, and (ii) every *field* has to have a meaningful PTS. If the million "pts has no value" and "non-monotonous DTS" in FFMpeg are real, how possible could it be to have a flawless playback of the original ts file (which I have)?

Comment: It definitely isn't likely for there to be a source problem that isn't picked up during playback and only happens during transcode. But when I want to be *sure* about something in a transport stream, I run it through an analyzer. Sometimes you pick up on something that is subtlety wrong that one decoder can correct that another chokes on.